# Amcharts - I want to add % symbol to category axis values

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I want to add custom label along with category axis values. 
I want to add percentage symbol to category axis values

Comment: please include your code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got answer to this..

added  "unit" :"%"

to categoryAxis

Comment: Can you give a more descriptive example, please? Any example code?